# Is the commenting/answering policy designed to force content generation, whilst maintaining a closed community?

Tags: discussion

I signed up to Stack Exchange recently, only to discover that the only way to participate in the conversation is to post questions first. This lead me to look closer at the site. What I discovered was lots of users posting random, and in many cases easily "Googled" questions to gain reputation. I have read the rules and can only assume that this policy is in place to force free content generation for the site, whilst maintaining a relatively closed community?

Comment: "can only assume" I guess you mean, can only conclude. But if you don't give your reasoning & ask for a critique of it, what is the point of this post?

Comment: On the surface, there is no reason to not let those who can help from participating. I am looking for an explanation for the policy?

Comment: One reason new users can't comment is that we would be overrun with spam comments - we already have to fight hard to keep spam questions and answers at bay.

Comment: Yes, I had reasoned that it was to limit spam, however there appears to be no moderation of links on new posts.

Comment: @DKenn New users are limited in how many links they can insert into a post, and we have automated systems in place to flag posts that contain suspected spam links. That doesn't stop people from *posting* spam links, but it does help bring them to people's attention and they're usually dealt with in a matter of minutes.

Comment: [ask] [Help] [meta.se] https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/134479

Answer (score 11):

I'd point you at the [Privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). You don't need reputation to post answers *or* questions. Comments need a little nuance to use effectively. There's users on SO with over a million reputation points and few or no questions.

The funny thing is the 'barrier to entry' for new users is one of the points of friction between folks, and that generally it *should* be harder to get away with trivially googled questions.

That said - depending on the site, 'quality' is more than how easy or hard a question is, but depends on things like how well documented the problem is and generally providing the information one needs to help work it out vs writing whatever comes to mind. "Farming easy to google questions" *isn't* desired behaviour - though we would likely want to be what google points people at when they have a problem

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I did try to post a couple reasonable answers only to be told by a moderator not to participate in discussions. In one instance the original poster edited their question to include what I had suggested. How would you suggest a new user who wishes to participate should proceed (without the ability to comment on anything but their own posts)?

Comment: I looked at the Privilege page - it is interesting that participation in Meta discussions is permitted, but not elsewhere.

Comment: Per site metas have no reputation/share reputation with their parent sites. Main meta... runs differently, and we want 'less' friction for people to participate from mechanics I guess.